# Linear Algebra Proof on Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices, with $B$ invertible. Assume that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with eigenvector $v$.

Prove that $\lambda$ is still an eigenvalue of $B−1AB$ with eigenvector $B−1v$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Could you please show your attempts made so far?

Comment: Yes! I know that a non-zero vector is an eigenvector for A with eigenvalue 
if Av=v. So I think I need to prove how AB both have the same eigenvector of ...I also have tried doing matrix multiplication with B-1AB and B-1v to try and see how I can get . I just don't know where the 
comes from. I know that Bv=v and so I know I can use this and that v=
λB-1v...I am just having problems formalizing what I know, if any of this makes sense.

Comment: I also know that Bv=v and v=B-1V,B-1v=(1/)v so I tried to break up B-1AB into separate pieces since it is cumulative, and then tried to get 
from AB using our rules but I got lost

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  When you typed $B-1$, did you mean `$B^{-1}$`, which is $B^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1):

If $Av=\lambda v$, then $(B^{-1}AB)(B^{-1}v)=B^{-1}A(BB^{-1})v=B^{-1}Av=B^{-1}\lambda v=\lambda (B^{-1}v)$,

so indeed $B^{-1}v$ is an eigenvector of $B^{-1}AB$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.